# number of distinct rotations of a string

Tags: combinatorics

How do we count the number of distinct rotations of string ?

string s="ABCD" has four distinct rotations "ABCD", "BCDA", "CDAB" and "DABC" but 
ABAB" has only 2: "ABAB" and "BABA". More so, a string like "BBBB" has only 1 rotation.

Comment: Very good question but the answer to your second question is obvious

Comment: @MayankDeora yes it is a permuatation and not a rotation ofd ABCD ,i had not noticed this earlier but the first part of problem is all i need .

Comment: If it would be permutation then answer is $\frac{n!}{p!.q!......}$ where p, q ...... is the number of repeated particular characters. But it must be rotation here

Comment: @MayankDeora  look at the problem , i eliminated the second half and now the problem is simply asking you the number of  distinct rotations ,nothing to do with permutations

Comment: I'm not sure what you asking? This seems trivial, if s is made of m times a k-length word then number of rotations is k. Of course if the small word is simple, meaning isn't made of x times smaller word...

Answer (score 1):

1. If the given string consists of only one character(like "***aaa***", "***bb***", "***ccccc***", etc.), then the number of distinct rotations is equal to **one**.
2. If the given string is of the form **(S1)^K** (repetition of a string "**S1**" K times, example "***abab***", "***abcab*c**", "***abcdabcdabc*d**"), then the number of distinct rotations is equal to the length of the string **S1**. (***Note***: The string **S1** should be selected such that from multiple options, its length should be the smallest.
   For example, for the string **abababab**, the sub string **S1** is **ab** and not **abab**.)
3. In all the remaining cases, the number of distinct rotations is equal to the length of the given string.

Comment: Rule #1 is just a case of #2 where `(S1)` has a length of one.

Comment: @allonhadaya, yes it is. However, I added it as a separate rule to avoid confusion. For instance, for the string "aaaa", one might say that it is of the form ("aa")^2, which would then make the result to be two (as per rule 2), which is not correct.

Comment: ah, interesting point... you could even have ambiguity for larger sequences: `abababab` may be `(ab)^4` or `(abab)^2`. I think the simple rule is to pick as short a value of `(S1)` as you can.